# Modificar consulta para agrupar por fecha

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta consulta

```
select s.Id_Sucursal, s.No_Serie, ir.Referencia, sr.F_Realizacion, p.Id_Producto, ds.Cantidad, p.Costo*ds.Cantidad as TotalGasto
from Servicios s inner join Clientes c
on s.Id_Sucursal=c.Id_Sucursal and s.Id_Clave_Cliente=c.Clave_Cliente inner join servicios_rellenados sr
on s.Id_Sucursal = sr.Id_Sucursal and s.Id_Servicio = sr.Id_Servicio inner join DetalleServicios ds
on ds.Id_Sucursal = s.Id_Sucursal and ds.Servicio_FK = s.Id_Servicio inner join Producto p
on ds.Producto_FK = p.Clave_Eq_Sisco and ds.Id_Sucursal = p.Id_Sucursal inner join Informa_Rentas ir
on ir.No_Serie = s.No_Serie and ir.Estatus='A' left join Lineas l
on p.Linea = l.Id_Linea and p.Id_Sucursal = l.Id_Sucursal
where ir.Estatus = 'a' and s.Id_Servicio in (select Id_Servicio from Servicios where No_Serie in(select No_Serie from Informa_Rentas where Estatus = 'a'))
and s.Id_Sucursal='CORDOBA'
order by No_Serie, F_Realizacion
```

Que me genera un resultado de este tipo:

```
Id_Sucursal     No_Serie    Referencia      F_Realizacion               Id_Producto     Cantidad    TotalGasto
CORDOBA     07H6BJFB009XV       3228        2018-02-06 00:00:00.000     2619                1           10621.96
CORDOBA     07H6BJFB009XV       3228        2018-02-06 00:00:00.000     2741                1           291.07
CORDOBA     07H6BJFB009XV       3228        2018-02-06 00:00:00.000     2246                1           200.00
CORDOBA     07H6BJFB009XV       3228        2018-03-01 00:00:00.000     1219                1           82.32
CORDOBA     07H6BJFB009XV       3228        2018-03-01 00:00:00.000     2246                1           200.00
CORDOBA     07H6BJFB009XV       3228        2018-03-08 00:00:00.000     1219                1           82.32
CORDOBA     07H6BJFB009XV       3228        2018-04-10 00:00:00.000     1219                2           164.64
CORDOBA     07H6BJFB009XV       3228        2018-04-30 00:00:00.000     1219                1           82.32
CORDOBA     07H6BJFB009XV       3228        2018-04-30 00:00:00.000     2246                1           200.00
CORDOBA     07H6BJFB009XV       3228        2018-06-11 00:00:00.000     1219                2           164.64
CORDOBA     07H6BJFB009XV       3228        2018-07-03 00:00:00.000     2475                1           250.00
```

Cómo podría modificar la consulta para que agrupe por No_Serie, Referencia, mes y sume el TotalGasto? La suma de TotalGasto también sería por mes.

El resultado esperado es este:

```
Id_Sucursal     No_Serie    Referencia      F_Realizacion               TotalGasto
CORDOBA     07H6BJFB009XV       3228        2018-02-06                  11113.03
CORDOBA     07H6BJFB009XV       3228        2018-03-01                  364.64
CORDOBA     07H6BJFB009XV       3228        2018-04-10                  446.96
CORDOBA     07H6BJFB009XV       3228        2018-06-11                  164.64
CORDOBA     07H6BJFB009XV       3228        2018-07-03                  250.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo así:

```
select s.Id_Sucursal,
       s.No_Serie, 
       ir.Referencia, 
       DATEPART(YEAR, sr.F_Realizacion) as Anio, 
       DATEPART(MONTH, sr.F_Realizacion) as Mes, 
       SUM(p.Costo*ds.Cantidad) as TotalGasto

       from Servicios s inner join Clientes c
       on s.Id_Sucursal=c.Id_Sucursal and s.Id_Clave_Cliente=c.Clave_Cliente inner join servicios_rellenados sr
       on s.Id_Sucursal = sr.Id_Sucursal and s.Id_Servicio = sr.Id_Servicio inner 
       join DetalleServicios ds
       on ds.Id_Sucursal = s.Id_Sucursal and ds.Servicio_FK = s.Id_Servicio inner join Producto p
       on ds.Producto_FK = p.Clave_Eq_Sisco and ds.Id_Sucursal = p.Id_Sucursal inner join Informa_Rentas ir
       on ir.No_Serie = s.No_Serie and ir.Estatus='A' left join Lineas l
       on p.Linea = l.Id_Linea and p.Id_Sucursal = l.Id_Sucursal
       where ir.Estatus = 'a' and s.Id_Servicio in (select Id_Servicio from Servicios where No_Serie in(select No_Serie from Informa_Rentas where Estatus = 'a'))
       and s.Id_Sucursal='CORDOBA'

    GROUP BY s.Id_Sucursal,
             s.No_Serie, 
             ir.Referencia, 
             DATEPART(YEAR, sr.F_Realizacion) as Anio, 
             DATEPART(MONTH, sr.F_Realizacion) as Mes
    ORDER BY s.Id_Sucursal, No_Serie, DATEPART(YEAR, sr.F_Realizacion), DATEPART(MONTH, sr.F_Realizacion)
```

Detalle:

- El patrón es: cada columna que vas a agrupar debe estar en el `select` y en el `group by`, de hecho para que la sentencia sea correcta no puede haber columnas en el `select` que no esten en el `group by`.
- A menos claro que la uses en una función e agregación como `SUM(p.Costo*ds.Cantidad)`
- para agrupar por mes, hay que "partir" la fecha en año y mes con `DATEPART()`

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Funciona perfecto!